# Is there power reflected when Fresnel Transmission Coefficient is 1?

Tags: geometric-optics

Suppose a ray does not meet the total internal reflection condition and is transmitted fully through an interface (i.e. Fresnel Transmission Coefficient = 1), can we still expect any power being reflected for that particular ray? Whether it is a ray or wave model, will there be some power coming back to the original medium?

Answer (score 2):

To conserve energy,
$$1=R+T+A,$$
where $R$, $T$, and $A$ are the power reflection, transmission, and absorption coefficients, respectively (and we assume that scattering is bundled into $R$ and/or $A$). These are all positive, real numbers.

Therefore, if $T=1$, $R=A=0$.